# Parse from base64 string via protobuf for javascript

Tags: javascript, django, protocol-buffers

I want to do following: feed a binary string of protobuf message encoded to base 64 in Python to server and then decode it back to entity via Protobuf for Javascript. I have the following code in view:

```
...
result = data_sample.SerializeToString()
result = base64.b64encode(result)
return render(request, 'pr22/index.html', {'result': result})
```

in template:

```
<script src="static/Long.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/ByteBuffer.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/ProtoBuf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ProtoBuf = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
    var builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("static/schema.proto");

</script>
```

what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Builder#wiki-decoding-from-an-arraybuffer-a-bytebuffer-a-node-buffer-or-a-base64-string)! :P

... but basically you'll want something like this:

```
var YourMessage = builder.build("YourMessage");
var myMessage = YourMessage.decode64("{{result|safe}}");
```